# Sorting arrays in NumPy by column

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, scipy

How do I sort a NumPy array by its nth column?

For example, given:

```
a = array([[9, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6],
           [7, 0, 5]])
```

I want to sort the rows of `a` by the second column to obtain:

```
array([[7, 0, 5],
       [9, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 182, accepted):

[@steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208339/steve-tjoa)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column/2828121#2828121) is actually the most elegant way of doing it.

For the "correct" way see the order keyword argument of [numpy.ndarray.sort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html#numpy.ndarray.sort)

However, you'll need to view your array as an array with fields (a structured array).

The "correct" way is quite ugly if you didn't initially define your array with fields...

As a quick example, to sort it and return a copy:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[0,0,1]])

In [3]: np.sort(a.view('i8,i8,i8'), order=['f1'], axis=0).view(np.int)
Out[3]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

To sort it in-place:

```
In [6]: a.view('i8,i8,i8').sort(order=['f1'], axis=0) #<-- returns None

In [7]: a
Out[7]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

@Steve's really is the most elegant way to do it, as far as I know...

The only advantage to this method is that the "order" argument is a list of the fields to order the search by. For example, you can sort by the second column, then the third column, then the first column by supplying order=['f1','f2','f0'].

Comment: In my numpy 1.6.1rc1, it raises `ValueError: new type not compatible with array.`

Comment: Would it make sense to file a feature request that the "correct" way be made less ugly?

Comment: What if the values in the array are `float`? Should I change anything?

Comment: If you have transposed ``a`` before getting to this point in the code, you will need to take a full copy so as to get the proper meaning from the ``view`` method. [See this quension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19826315/2399799).

Comment: In reply to @Marco's question, you can use ``a.dtype.str`` to get the ``'i8'`` or ``'f8'`` string...which you then need to build into the full comma-delimited string.

Comment: And for hybrid type like `a = np.array([['a',1,2,3],['b',4,5,6],['c',0,0,1]])` what approach should I follow?

Comment: @MrMartin - Based on this and some of your other comments, it sounds like you have data with a common type in each column (e.g. spreadsheet-like data).  If so, have a look at `pandas`. It will simplify a lot of the type of operations you're wanting to do.

Comment: One major advantage of this method over Steve's is that it allows very large arrays to be sorted in place. For a sufficiently large array, the indices returned by `np.argsort` may themselve take up quite a lot of memory, and on top of that, indexing with an array will also generate a copy of the array that is being sorted.

Comment: @Clippit `new type not compatible with array.` can also be caused by NaN values. Use `np.nan_to_num(a)` to fix.

Comment: @dan-man: Thanks for the link (two years later...). If `array.flags.c_contiguous` is true, is that a guarantee that the view method will work?

Comment: Can someone explain the `'i8,i8,i8'`? This is for each column or each row? What should change if sorting a different dtype? How do I find out how many bits are being used? Thank you

Comment: This sorts `[[2,4],
[1, 3],
[2, 2],
[1, 1]]` into `[[1,1],
[2, 2],
[1, 3],
[2, 4]]` instead of `[[2,1],
[1, 2],
[2, 3],
[1, 4]]` if sorted based on 2nd col.

Comment: Sorry bad example. This sorts `[[2, 3],
[1, 2],
[2, 1]]` into `[[1, 1],
[2, 3],
[2, 2]]` instead of `[[2, 3],
[1, 1],
[2, 2]]` if sorted based on 1st col.

Comment: @JoeKingtonwhat does (order=['f1'] stand for ? field 1 ? cant figure out from https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html

Comment: N.B. don't forget a floating point precision. I got burned by this. My multi-column sort "wasn't working" as expected and I realized it was due to precision errors.

Answer (score 1002):

To sort by the second column of `a`:

```
a[a[:, 1].argsort()]
```

Comment: If you want the reverse sort, modify this to be `a[a[:,1].argsort()[::-1]]`

Comment: Looks simple and works! Is it faster than `np.sort` or not?

Comment: I find this easier to read: `ind = np.argsort( a[:,1] ); a = a[ind]`

Comment: a[a[:,k].argsort()] is the same as a[a[:,k].argsort(),:]. This generalizes to the other dimension (sort cols using a row): a[:,a[j,:].argsort()] (hope i typed that right.)

Comment: As far as I can see this does not generalize to the case that one would want to sort by multiple columns `cols`, i.e. all columns. For that case I do `a[np.lexsort(a.T[cols])]` where `[cols]` could be left out if sorted by all columns and from right to left. This also allows to define the order of columns by which to sort, i.e `cols = range(a.shape[1])[::-1]`.

Comment: needed to use b = a[a[:, 1].argsort()]  then b is the sorted one

Comment: @pippo1980 , I think this comment is important. The answer is a bit misleading as if `a` itself changes to the sorted version only with `a[a[:, 1].argsort()]`

Comment: @SangjunLee  re-tried that just now with online python compiler and its true need to use b = ... to change the indexes. So why its that array.argsort() works diffferent than argsort(array) ??

Comment: @SangjunLee they dont they work exactly the same :  Returns the indices that would sort an array. thats why b = .... is needed

Answer (score 59):

You can sort on multiple columns as per Steve Tjoa's method by using a stable sort like mergesort and sorting the indices from the least significant to the most significant columns:

```
a = a[a[:,2].argsort()] # First sort doesn't need to be stable.
a = a[a[:,1].argsort(kind='mergesort')]
a = a[a[:,0].argsort(kind='mergesort')]
```

This sorts by column 0, then 1, then 2.

Comment: Why does First Sort not need to be stable?

Comment: Good question - stable means that when there's a tie you maintain the original order, and the original order of the unsorted file is irrelevant.

Comment: This seems like a really super important point. having a list that silently doesn’t sort would be bad.

Answer (score 26):

In case someone wants to make use of sorting at a critical part of their programs here's a performance comparison for the different proposals:

```
import numpy as np
table = np.random.rand(5000, 10)

%timeit table.view('f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8').sort(order=['f9'], axis=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.88 ms per loop

%timeit table[table[:,9].argsort()]
10000 loops, best of 3: 180 µs per loop

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(table)
%timeit df.sort_values(9, ascending=True)
1000 loops, best of 3: 400 µs per loop
```

So, it looks like indexing with [argsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) is the quickest method so far...

Answer (score 25):

From [the NumPy mailing list](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2008-December/039332.html), here's another solution:

```
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 0],
      [2, 2]])
>>> a[np.lexsort(np.fliplr(a).T)]
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

Comment: The correct generalization is `a[np.lexsort(a.T[cols])]`. where `cols=[1]` in the original question.

Answer (score 23):

As [the Python documentation wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) suggests:

```
a = ([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [0, 0, 1]]); 
a = sorted(a, key=lambda a_entry: a_entry[1]) 
print a
```

Output:

```
[[[0, 0, 1], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]
```

Comment: With this solution, one gets a list instead of a NumPy array, so this might not always be convenient (takes more memory, is probably slower, etc.).

Comment: this "solution" is slower by the most-upvoted answer by a factor of ... well, close to infinity actually

Comment: @Jivan Actually, this solution is faster than the most-upvoted answer by a factor of 5 https://imgur.com/a/IbqtPBL

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins But this doesn't do the whole job. Produces a list instead of an array. I get similar times as yours (3.02 ms vs 549 μs), but if I finish this by applying `np.array` to the result, it goes up to 4.3 ms.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem.

**My Problem:**

I want to calculate an SVD and need to sort my [eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) in descending order. But I want to keep the mapping between eigenvalues and eigenvectors.
My eigenvalues were in the first row and the corresponding eigenvector below it in the same column.

So I want to sort a two-dimensional array column-wise by the first row in descending order.

**My Solution**

```
a = a[::, a[0,].argsort()[::-1]]
```

So how does this work?

`a[0,]` is just the first row I want to sort by.

Now I use argsort to get the order of indices.

I use `[::-1]` because I need descending order.

Lastly I use `a[::, ...]` to get a view with the columns in the right order.

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[21,20,19,18,17],[16,15,14,13,12],[11,10,9,8,7],[6,5,4,3,2]])
y=np.argsort(a[:,2],kind='mergesort')# a[:,2]=[19,14,9,4]
a=a[y]
print(a)
```

Desired output is `[[6,5,4,3,2],[11,10,9,8,7],[16,15,14,13,12],[21,20,19,18,17]]`

note that `argsort(numArray)` returns the indices of an `numArray` as it was supposed to be arranged in a sorted manner.

example

```
x=np.array([8,1,5]) 
z=np.argsort(x) #[1,3,0] are the **indices of the predicted sorted array**
print(x[z]) #boolean indexing which sorts the array on basis of indices saved in z
```

answer would be `[1,5,8]`

Comment: You sure its not [1,2,0]?

Answer (score 3):

A little more complicated `lexsort` example - descending on the 1st column, secondarily ascending on the 2nd.  The tricks with `lexsort` are that it sorts on rows (hence the `.T`), and gives priority to the last.

```
In [120]: b=np.array([[1,2,1],[3,1,2],[1,1,3],[2,3,4],[3,2,5],[2,1,6]])
In [121]: b
Out[121]: 
array([[1, 2, 1],
       [3, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 2, 5],
       [2, 1, 6]])
In [122]: b[np.lexsort(([1,-1]*b[:,[1,0]]).T)]
Out[122]: 
array([[3, 1, 2],
       [3, 2, 5],
       [2, 1, 6],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [1, 1, 3],
       [1, 2, 1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas Approach Just For Completeness:

```
a = np.array([[9, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 0, 5]])              
a = pd.DataFrame(a) 

             
a.sort_values(1, ascending=True).to_numpy()
array([[7, 0, 5], # '1' means sort by second column
       [9, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

[prl900](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1825593/prl900)
Did the Benchmark, comparing with the accepted answer:

```
%timeit pandas_df.sort_values(9, ascending=True)
1000 loops, best of 3: 400 µs per loop

%timeit numpy_table[numpy_table[:,9].argsort()]
10000 loops, best of 3: 180 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution considering **all** columns (more compact way of [J.J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3329564/j-j)'s answer);

```
ar=np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1],
             [1, 0, 1, 0],
             [0, 1, 0, 0],
             [1, 0, 0, 1],
             [0, 0, 1, 0],
             [1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Sort with lexsort,

```
ar[np.lexsort(([ar[:, i] for i in range(ar.shape[1]-1, -1, -1)]))]
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply using sort, use column number based on which you want to sort.

```
a = np.array([1,1], [1,-1], [-1,1], [-1,-1]])
print (a)
a = a.tolist() 
a = np.array(sorted(a, key=lambda a_entry: a_entry[0]))
print (a)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question but if you need to generalize this to a higher than 2 dimension arrays, here is the solution than can be easily generalized:

```
np.einsum('ij->ij', a[a[:,1].argsort(),:])
```

This is an overkill for two dimensions and `a[a[:,1].argsort()]` would be enough per @steve's answer, however that answer cannot be generalized to higher dimensions. You can find [an example of 3D array in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61449930/is-there-another-way-for-sorting-3d-numpy-array-by-column-values/61451923#61451923)

Output:

```
[[7 0 5]
 [9 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

#for sorting along column 1

```
indexofsort=np.argsort(dataset[:,0],axis=-1,kind='stable') 
dataset   = dataset[indexofsort,:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def sort_np_array(x, column=None, flip=False):
    x = x[np.argsort(x[:, column])]
    if flip:
        x = np.flip(x, axis=0)
    return x
```

Array in the original question:

```py
a = np.array([[9, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 0, 5]])
```

The result of the `sort_np_array` function as expected by the author of the question:

```py
sort_np_array(a, column=1, flip=False)
```

```
[2]: array([[7, 0, 5],
            [9, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5204280/13890678

I found a more "generic" answer using [structured array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html).
I think one advantage of this method is that the code is easier to read.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[9, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6],
           [7, 0, 5]])

struct_a = np.core.records.fromarrays(
    a.transpose(), names="col1, col2, col3", formats="i8, i8, i8"
)
struct_a.sort(order="col2")

print(struct_a)
```

```
[(7, 0, 5) (9, 2, 3) (4, 5, 6)]
```