# Convert numpy array to numpy record array

Tags: python, numpy

I try to convert a 10x2 array to a record, by giving names to each column.

I tried it so:

```
t = arange (10)
>>> n = dstack([t,
                roll (t, 1),
                roll (t, -1)])[0]
... ... >>> 
>>> n = n[:,1:3]
>>> n
array([[9, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 5],
       [4, 6],
       [5, 7],
       [6, 8],
       [7, 9],
       [8, 0]])
>>> nt = [('left', int), ('right', int)]
>>> array (n, nt)
array([[(9, 9), (1, 1)],
       [(0, 0), (2, 2)],
       [(1, 1), (3, 3)],
       [(2, 2), (4, 4)],
       [(3, 3), (5, 5)],
       [(4, 4), (6, 6)],
       [(5, 5), (7, 7)],
       [(6, 6), (8, 8)],
       [(7, 7), (9, 9)],
       [(8, 8), (0, 0)]], 
      dtype=[('left', '<i8'), ('right', '<i8')])
>>>
```

To my surprize, the elements of each row are tuples instead of numbers of type int.

How can I correct this, and make each row of n look like `[ 9,1 ]` instead of `[(9, 9), (1, 1)]` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a 2D numpy array to a structured array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622850/converting-a-2d-numpy-array-to-a-structured-array)

Comment: I read this post, and despite my efforts to understand it and convert as I want, I cannot find the answer there. On the other hand the answers received here so far works .

Comment: Yeah the construction of recarrays from existing arrays is a bit weird since you're taking what used to be separate elements into one tuple of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is hopefully a better way in pure numpy, but to get you started:

```
>>> nt = [('left', int), ('right', int)]
>>> n
array([[9, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 5],
       [4, 6],
       [5, 7],
       [6, 8],
       [7, 9],
       [8, 0]])

>>> out = np.array(np.zeros(n.shape[0]),nt)
>>> out
array([(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0),
       (0, 0), (0, 0)],
      dtype=[('left', '<i8'), ('right', '<i8')])

>>> out['left']=n[:,0]
>>> out['right']=n[:,1]

>>> out
array([(9, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 8),
       (7, 9), (8, 0)],
      dtype=[('left', '<i8'), ('right', '<i8')])

>>> out['left']
array([9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Of course there is the pandas answer:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(n,columns=['left','right'])
>>> df
   left  right
0     9      1
1     0      2
2     1      3
3     2      4
4     3      5
5     4      6
6     5      7
7     6      8
8     7      9
9     8      0
```

Something nice about pandas dataframes:

```
>>> df.values
array([[9, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 5],
       [4, 6],
       [5, 7],
       [6, 8],
       [7, 9],
       [8, 0]])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a view with a new dtype and it looks a the same data:

```py
In [150]: nt = [('left',np.int),('right',np.int)]

In [151]: n
Out[151]: 
array([[9, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 5],
       [4, 6],
       [5, 7],
       [6, 8],
       [7, 9],
       [8, 0]])

In [152]: n.view(nt)
Out[152]: 
array([[(9, 1)],
       [(0, 2)],
       [(1, 3)],
       [(2, 4)],
       [(3, 5)],
       [(4, 6)],
       [(5, 7)],
       [(6, 8)],
       [(7, 9)],
       [(8, 0)]], 
      dtype=[('left', '<i8'), ('right', '<i8')])
```

This maintains the 2d shape, though:

```py
In [160]: n_struct = n.view(nt)

In [161]: n_struct.shape
Out[161]: (10, 1)

In [162]: n_struct = n.view(nt).reshape(n.shape[0])

In [163]: n_struct
Out[163]: 
array([(9, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 8),
       (7, 9), (8, 0)], 
      dtype=[('left', '<i8'), ('right', '<i8')])
```

As you asked, access is as such:

```py
In [170]: n_struct['left']
Out[170]: array([9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

In [171]: n_struct['right']
Out[171]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])
```

A warning, from @Ophion, is that this only works if the dtypes are compatible, because `ndarray.view(dtype)` interprets the original data as if it were the given dtype, it does not *convert* the data to the new given dtype.  In other words, (from the documentation),

> `a.view(some_dtype)` constructs a view of the array's memory with a different data-type.  This can cause a reinterpretation of the bytes of memory.

Comment: seems interesting, but now the array is of tuples. I need to execute this operation very often, and I need something really fast. On the other hand, how can 'left' extract the first element from an array of  tuples ?

Comment: That is what a `record` array is: an array of tuples (since your `dtype` is a tuple of two `int`s).

Comment: Can you define other type, such that to get directly the columnm by name, with only 1 operation ?

Comment: I am using python 2.7 . For me it does not work. n.view (nt) => ValueError: new type not compatible with array.

Comment: This is a really nice way to do this, the one thing that I would mention is to be extremely careful about the `dtype`. There is no checking and will either cause an error or wonky results if the `dtypes` do not match. @alinsoar I would check the `dtype` of your array, its likely the cause.

Comment: @alinsoar What do you mean by "to get directly the columnm by name, with only 1 operation"?  There must be two operations: one to create the record/structured array, and a second to access a column.

Comment: @Ophion Yes of course, you wouldn't want to have it interpret the data as strings, e.g.  It's important to note that this views the data and interprets at as the given type, it does not _convert_ it to the given type.

Comment: I made an optimization , and to clean the code, I gave name to columns, to distinguish their meaning into a synamic cyclic buffer with many nodes. I did none of these both answers literaly, but I used ideas from both answers.

Answer (score 1):

If the underlying dtypes are not compatible, the `view` approach does not work.  The fallback option is to fill the record array with a list of tuples:

```
In [128]: x=np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)

In [129]: y=np.zeros((4,),dtype=[('x','f'),('y','f'),('z','f')])

In [130]: y
Out[130]: 
array([(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')])

In [131]: y[:]=[tuple(row) for row in x]

In [132]: y
Out[132]: 
array([(0.0, 1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0, 5.0), (6.0, 7.0, 8.0), (9.0, 10.0, 11.0)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')])
```

this list of tuples can be used in the initial construction:

```
In [135]: np.array([tuple(row) for row in x],y.dtype)
Out[135]: 
array([(0.0, 1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0, 5.0), (6.0, 7.0, 8.0), (9.0, 10.0, 11.0)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')])
```