# how to make a numpy recarray from column arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a pair of numpy arrays; here's a simple equivalent example:

```
t = np.linspace(0,1,100)
data = ((t % 0.1) * 50).astype(np.uint16)
```

I want these to be columns in a numpy recarray of dtype `f8, i2`. This is the only way I can seem to get what I want:

```
X = np.array(zip(t,data),dtype=[('t','f8'),('data','i2')])
```

But is it the right way if my data values are large? I want to minimize the unnecessary overhead of shifting around data.

This seems like it should be an easy problem but I can't find a good example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A straight-forward way to do this is with [`numpy.rec.fromarrays`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.core.records.fromarrays.html). In your case:

```
np.rec.fromarrays([t, data], dtype=[('t','f8'),('data','i2')])
```

or simply

```
np.rec.fromarrays([t, data], names='t,data', formats='f8,i2')
```

would work.

Alternative approaches are also given at [Converting a 2D numpy array to a structured array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622850/converting-a-2d-numpy-array-to-a-structured-array)