# Duplicate values on Numpy array when setting dtype

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have two one-dimensional arrays that we will call `x` and `y`, for convenience:

```
x = np.array([1., 3.])
y = np.array([2, 4])
```

And I want to concatenate them into a structured array. The desired output is:

```
array([( 1., 2), ( 3., 4)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<i8')])
```

But by doing:

```
my_array = np.array([x, y]).T
my_array = my_array.astype([('x', float), ('y', int)])
```

I get the following:

```
array([[( 1., 1), ( 2., 2)],
       [( 3., 3), ( 4., 4)]], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<i8')])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622850/converting-a-2d-numpy-array-to-a-structured-array shows how to construct a `recarray` with `fromrecords`.  But the problem is better solved with `fromarrays`.  The `x` and `y` here are fields, not records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.rec.fromarrays`:

```
np.rec.fromarrays([x, y], dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<i8')])
# rec.array([( 1., 2), ( 3., 4)], 
#           dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<i8')])
```

Answer (score 0):

[Converting a 2D numpy array to a structured array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622850/converting-a-2d-numpy-array-to-a-structured-array) isn't quite a duplicate.  There the starting point is

```
[("Hello",2.5,3),("World",3.6,2)]
```

The accepted solution uses `np.rec.fromarrays`, but it has to transpose the input.  The short solution uses `np.fromrecords`.

But a look at the code for `fromarrays` suggests a simple way to do this, especially if you can't recall where all these `recarray` functions are hiding.

```
In [200]: x = np.array([1., 3.])
     ...: y = np.array([2, 4])

In [201]: dt = [('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<i8')]

In [204]: arr = np.empty(x.shape[0], dtype=dt)
In [205]: for n, v in zip(arr.dtype.names, [x, y]):
     ...:     arr[n] = v

In [206]: arr
Out[206]: 
array([( 1., 2), ( 3., 4)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<i8')])
```

Like many `recfunctions`, `fromarrays`, creates a new blank array of the desired shape and dtype, and copies values by field name.

Although the `fromrecords` suggests a different approach - use `zip` to transpose the arrays:

```
In [210]: list(zip(*[x,y]))
Out[210]: [(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)]
```

This is a list of tuples, so I can use it directly in a structured array creation statement:

```
In [212]: np.array(_, dtype=dt)
Out[212]: 
array([( 1., 2), ( 3., 4)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<i8')])
```

Copying fields should be faster, assuming that the real array will have many more records than fields.