# Structured array from an array and np.dtype object

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dtype

The following code constructs a NumPy array with a dtype object:

```py
dt = np.dtype([
    ("index", np.int32),
    ("timestamp", np.int32),
    ("volume", np.float32)
])

arr = np.array([
    [0, 20, 3],
    [1, 21, 2],
    [2, 23, 8],
    [3, 26, 5],
    [4, 31, 9]
]).astype(dt)
```

The expected result of `arr` would be:

```py
>>> arr
array([[  0,  20, 334.],
       [  1,  21, 254.],
       [  2,  23, 823.],
       [  3,  26, 521.],
       [  4,  31, 943.]])

>>> arr[0]
array([  0,  20, 334.])
```

But what the code above is creating is actually this:

```py
>>> arr
array([[(  0,   0,   0.), ( 20,  20,  20.), (334, 334, 334.)],
       [(  1,   1,   1.), ( 21,  21,  21.), (254, 254, 254.)],
       [(  2,   2,   2.), ( 23,  23,  23.), (823, 823, 823.)],
       [(  3,   3,   3.), ( 26,  26,  26.), (521, 521, 521.)],
       [(  4,   4,   4.), ( 31,  31,  31.), (943, 943, 943.)]],
      dtype=[('index', '<i4'), ('timestamp', '<i4'), ('volume', '<f4')])

>>> arr[0]
array([(  0,   0,   0.), ( 20,  20,  20.), (334, 334, 334.)],
      dtype=[('index', '<i4'), ('timestamp', '<i4'), ('volume', '<f4')])
```

Why is NumPy creating a version of every value for every data type instead of mapping each column to its own data type (and only this one)? I'm guessing that I did something wrong there. Is there a way to get to the result I was expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that for the structured array creation you need a list of tuples. This is mentioned in [Structured Datatype Creation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#structured-datatype-creation), where it states that among other less common methods of array creation, the input data must be a *list of tuples, one tuple per field*.

So what you can do is turn your array into a list of tuples (`zip` will be convenient here) and build the structured array from it using [`np.fromiter`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) and specifying `dt` as `dtype`:

```
np.fromiter(zip(*arr.T), dtype=dt)
array([(0, 20, 3.), (1, 21, 2.), (2, 23, 8.), (3, 26, 5.), (4, 31, 9.)],
      dtype=[('index', '<i4'), ('timestamp', '<i4'), ('volume', '<f4')])
```

Another (lesser known) approach as mentioned by @hpaulj in the comments, is using [`np.lib.recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.rec.html#numpy.lib.recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured), which can be used to directly construct the structured array from `arr` and the dtype object with:

```
np.lib.recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured(a, dt)
array([(0, 20, 3.), (1, 21, 2.), (2, 23, 8.), ..., (2, 23, 8.),
       (3, 26, 5.), (4, 31, 9.)],
      dtype=[('index', '<i4'), ('timestamp', '<i4'), ('volume', '<f4')])
```

Or based on [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622850/converting-a-2d-numpy-array-to-a-structured-array) there's also the possibility to create a [record array](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/user/basics.rec.html#record-arrays), an ndarray subclass, very similar to a structured array in terms of usage, that comes with several associated helper functions, such as [`np.core.records.fromarrays`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.core.records.fromarrays.html) that can be used for the creation of the array as in a simple way:

```
np.core.records.fromarrays(arr.T, 
                           names='index, timestamp, volume', 
                           formats = '<i4, <i4, <f4')
rec.array([(0, 20, 3.), (1, 21, 2.), (2, 23, 8.), (3, 26, 5.),
           (4, 31, 9.)],
          dtype=[('index', '<i4'), ('timestamp', '<i4'), ('volume', '<f4')])
```

Or to create it from the `np.dtype` object:

```
names, dtypes = list(zip(*dt.descr))
np.core.records.fromarrays(arr.transpose(), 
                           names= ', '.join(names), 
                           formats = ', '.join(dtypes))
```

Timings comparing the mentioned methods, and some other possible approaches:

```
a = np.concatenate([arr]*1000, axis=0)

%%timeit 
np.core.records.fromarrays(a.T, 
                           names='index, timestamp, volume', 
                           formats = '<i4, <i4, <f4')
# 57.9 µs ± 1.18 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit np.lib.recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured(a, dt)
# 79.6 µs ± 1.32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit np.fromiter(zip(*a.T), dtype=dt)
#2.1 ms ± 69.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit np.fromiter(map(tuple, a), dtype=dt)
#6.34 ms ± 65.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit np.array(list(zip(*a.T)), dtype=dt)
# 2.17 ms ± 107 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: ah! but then you'd lose the ability to do things like isolate columns quickly with `arr[:, 0]` for instance

Comment: I mean, you can use `arr["index"]` but I'm wondering if, when using tuples like this, performance would be equivalent as the "pure array" form

Comment: You can index on the names, such as `a['index']`  @jivan

Comment: Well I'm unsure tbh until what point working with structured arrays is optimized in numpy as opposed to regular ndarrays, but I'd guess that performance does worsen @jivan

Comment: yes, that's what I'm thinking as well. Gonna stick to regular ndarrays for now, even if that mean having columns which should be `np.int8` being cast into `np.float64`...

Comment: You can also use `numpy.lib.recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured`

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj , first time I see this one, but seems the most straight forward way of doing this. Added the timings fyi

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot change data-type for object array.` when using `unstructured_to_structured`.