# Sort numpy matrix row values in ascending order

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy

I have this following numpy matrix that I want to sort in ascending order **based on the 3rd column values**.

```
[[  3.05706500e+06   4.98000000e+01  -2.62500070e+01  -9.38135544e+01]
 [  3.05706600e+06   4.98000000e+01  -3.00000056e+01  -9.38135544e+01]
 [  3.05706700e+06   4.98000000e+01  -3.37500042e+01  -9.38135544e+01]
 [  3.05706800e+06   4.98000000e+01  -3.75000028e+01  -9.38135544e+01]]
```

This is the matrix I actually want.

```
[[  3.05706800e+06   4.98000000e+01  -3.75000028e+01  -9.38135544e+01]
 [  3.05706700e+06   4.98000000e+01  -3.37500042e+01  -9.38135544e+01]
 [  3.05706600e+06   4.98000000e+01  -3.00000056e+01  -9.38135544e+01]
 [  3.05706500e+06   4.98000000e+01  -2.62500070e+01  -9.38135544e+01]]
```

How do I do this using just numpy? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [sorting arrays in numpy by column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Given your array

```
>>> arr
array([[  3.05706500e+06,   4.98000000e+01,  -2.62500070e+01,
         -9.38135544e+01],
       [  3.05706600e+06,   4.98000000e+01,  -3.00000056e+01,
         -9.38135544e+01],
       [  3.05706700e+06,   4.98000000e+01,  -3.37500042e+01,
         -9.38135544e+01],
       [  3.05706800e+06,   4.98000000e+01,  -3.75000028e+01,
         -9.38135544e+01]])
```

you can simply use numpy.sort with axis=0 to sort it as desired

```
>>> numpy.sort(arr,axis=0)
array([[  3.05706500e+06,   4.98000000e+01,  -3.75000028e+01,
         -9.38135544e+01],
       [  3.05706600e+06,   4.98000000e+01,  -3.37500042e+01,
         -9.38135544e+01],
       [  3.05706700e+06,   4.98000000e+01,  -3.00000056e+01,
         -9.38135544e+01],
       [  3.05706800e+06,   4.98000000e+01,  -2.62500070e+01,
         -9.38135544e+01]])
>>>
```

---

I believe my previous answer was wrong as I misunderstood the question. Here is the correct answer

```
>>> arr[arr[:,2].argsort()]
array([[  3.05706800e+06,   4.98000000e+01,  -3.75000028e+01,
         -9.38135544e+01],
       [  3.05706700e+06,   4.98000000e+01,  -3.37500042e+01,
         -9.38135544e+01],
       [  3.05706600e+06,   4.98000000e+01,  -3.00000056e+01,
         -9.38135544e+01],
       [  3.05706500e+06,   4.98000000e+01,  -2.62500070e+01,
         -9.38135544e+01]])
>>>
```

Comment: You are sorting every column, not with respect to 3rd column. The output is right, but I am not that this is the method that OP was looking for.

Comment: @Akavall Thanks, I was yet to try out the solution. Thanks to you both!

Comment: I had to also specify the axis, i.e. sample[:,2].argsort(axis=0)

Comment: Hello. Could you please say how can I sort every matrix column in descending order?