# Sorting numpy mix-typed matrices

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, matrix

I would like to sort such type of (wider) matrices that contain same types per column but each column may have different types. This sort should perform so that all columns of a line stay together but lines order following the value of a defined column

```
[ 
[1, 0, 0.25,'ind1', 'pop2', 0.56],
[2, 0, 0.35,'ind2', 'pop2', 0.58],
[1, 0, 0.23,'ind1', 'pop1', 0.66],
...
]
```

Here I perform a sort algo by column 2 (floating point column)

```
[ 
[1, 0, 0.23,'ind1', 'pop1', 0.66],
[1, 0, 0.25,'ind1', 'pop2', 0.56],
[2, 0, 0.35,'ind2', 'pop2', 0.58],
...
]
```

Did it change if column contains char types?
thanks for help and advices, yet checked lexsort, sort, argsort...but probably in a wrong way.
Edit: I don't know why but if my matrix is defined as numpy.matrix(), argsort() method adds a dimension (so three dimension result), that doesn't happen if the matrix was defined using numpy.array(). If it can help further readers.

Comment: does your data type have named fields? It's much easier then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data type has named fields, you can use numpy.sort, with the field name you want to sort on specified in the "order" argument:

```
import numpy 

fieldTypes = ['i4', 'i4', 'f8', 'S4', 'S4', 'f8'] # data types of each field
fieldNames = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] # names of the fields, feel free to give more descriptive names

myType = numpy.dtype(zip(fieldNames, fieldTypes)) # Create a numpy data type based on the types and fields

a = numpy.array([(1, 0, 0.25,'ind1', 'pop2', 0.56),
(2, 0, 0.35,'ind2', 'pop2', 0.58),
(1, 0, 0.23,'ind1', 'pop1', 0.66)], dtype=myType) # Create the array with the right dtype

print numpy.sort(a, order=['c']) # sort based on column 'c'
```

Note that if you are creating an empty buffer or loading the numpy data from an existing file/buffer, you can still convert it to the dtype with named fields.

If you don't have named fields, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column) answer can help you, I recommend the approach suggested by @Steve Tjoa:

```
a[a[:,1].argsort()] # Replace 1 with the index you need
```

Comment: probably what I'm looking for but I don't know how to "declare" fields :-/

Comment: @sol I added example code on how to specify the dtype (i.e. "declare the fields")

Comment: hmmm... Seems this method doesn't work in python 3.7: 


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
      4 fieldNames = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] # names of the fields, feel free to give more descriptive names
      5 
----> 6 myType = numpy.dtype(zip(fieldNames, fieldTypes)) # Create a numpy data type based on the types and fields
      7 
      8 a = numpy.array([(1, 0, 0.25,'ind1', 'pop2', 0.56),

TypeError: data type not understood
```