# Transpose array and actually reorder memory

Tags: memory, numpy, transpose

I have a 3-D NumPy array, e.g.

```
a = np.random.random((2,3,5))
```

I would like to transpose the last two axes, i.e.

```
b = a.transpose(0,2,1)
```

However, I do not want a view with twiddled strides! I want to actually copy the array and reorder it *in memory*. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [`copy()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html) method will reorder to C-contiguous order by default:

```
b = a.transpose(0,2,1).copy()
```

---

Be careful: the [`copy()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) *function* has a different default behavior.  With the function, you must explicitly specify the order to ensure a C-contiguous copy:

```
b = np.copy(a.transpose(0,2,1), order='C')
```

(Note that the docstring for the function says that the ndarray method is the preferred method for creating an array copy.)

Comment: Thanks. The solution I had _just_ found before you posted yours was `b = np.zeros((2,5,3)); b[:] = a.transpose(0,2,1)`, but yours is much cleaner.

Answer (score 5):

Under the hood, the stride of b is different than a.

prefer to use [ascontiguousarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html), which will copy the memory when it's needed. Whereas `copy` will always copy memory.

Comment: This is a very good point, especially for complicated code on large data sets! Thanks!