# How to sort multidimensional array by column?

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

Is there a way to use the sort() method or any other method to sort a list by column? Lets say I have the list:

```
[
[John,2],
[Jim,9],
[Jason,1]
]
```

And I wanted to sort it so that it would look like this:

```
[
[Jason,1],
[John,2],
[Jim,9],
]
```

What would be the best approach to do this?

Edit:

Right now I am running into an index out of range error. I have a 2 dimensional array that is lets say 1000 rows b 3 columns. I want to sort it based on the third column. Is this the right code for that?

```
sorted_list = sorted(list_not_sorted, key=lambda x:x[2])
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column

Comment: Right now I am running into an index out of range error. I have a 2 dimensional array that is lets say 1000 rows b 3 columns. I want to sort it based on the third column. Is this the right code for that? sorted_list = sorted(list_not_sorted, key=lambda x:x[2])

Comment: In response to your edit, since lists are zero indexed, yes x[2] is the third column.  The moral of the story is, you can use a key and lambda or an actual function to sort by some stipulation in the `sorted` and `sort` functions.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Yes.  The `sorted` built-in accepts a `key` argument:

```
sorted(li,key=lambda x: x[1])
Out[31]: [['Jason', 1], ['John', 2], ['Jim', 9]]
```

note that `sorted` returns a new list.  If you want to sort in-place, use the `.sort` method of your list (which also, conveniently, accepts a `key` argument).

or alternatively,

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(li,key=itemgetter(1))
Out[33]: [['Jason', 1], ['John', 2], ['Jim', 9]]
```

[Read more on the python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/).

Comment: Might want to mention that this will return a new list.

Comment: Indeed. If you want to modify the original list, that would be `li.sort(key=whatever)`.

Comment: And how can I get the natural sorting? As in here sorted sorts based on the digit place and '411' will be sorted first then '67'.

Comment: @AbhishekJain The type of your data is string, which is why "411" is coming before "67". [Convert to number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int)

Answer (score 14):

You can use the sorted method with a key.

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x : x[1])
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `list.sort` with its optional [`key` parameter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions) and a [`lambda` expression](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions):

```
>>> lst = [
...     ['John',2],
...     ['Jim',9],
...     ['Jason',1]
... ]
>>> lst.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
>>> lst
[['Jason', 1], ['John', 2], ['Jim', 9]]
>>>
```

This will sort the list in-place.

---

Note that for large lists, it will be faster to use [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) instead of a `lambda`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lst = [
...     ['John',2],
...     ['Jim',9],
...     ['Jason',1]
... ]
>>> lst.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
>>> lst
[['Jason', 1], ['John', 2], ['Jim', 9]]
>>>
```

Comment: What exactly is the "lambda" key?

Comment: @user3024130 - The `lambda` creates an inline function for the `key` parameter.  I added a link to explain better.  Using a `lambda` would be no different than doing `def func(x): return x[1]` and then `lst.sort(key=func)`.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. How would you sort it from highest to lowest instead of lowest to highest?

Comment: @user3024130 - Simple.  Use this:  `lst.sort(key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)`.  `list.sort` also takes an optional `reverse` parameter.  If it is set to `True`, the list is sorted highest to lowest.  Otherwise, it is lowest to highest.

Answer (score 3):

```
sorted(list, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Note: this works on time variable too.

Answer (score 1):

The optional `key` parameter to `sort`/`sorted` is a function. The function is called for each item and the return values determine the ordering of the sort

```
>>> lst = [['John', 2], ['Jim', 9], ['Jason', 1]]
>>> def my_key_func(item):
...     print("The key for {} is {}".format(item, item[1]))
...     return item[1]
... 
>>> sorted(lst, key=my_key_func)
The key for ['John', 2] is 2
The key for ['Jim', 9] is 9
The key for ['Jason', 1] is 1
[['Jason', 1], ['John', 2], ['Jim', 9]]
```

taking the `print` out of the function leaves

```
>>> def my_key_func(item):
...     return item[1]
```

This function is simple enough to write "inline" as a lambda function

```
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda item: item[1])
[['Jason', 1], ['John', 2], ['Jim', 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

below solution worked for me in case of required number is float.
Solution:

```
table=sorted(table,key=lambda x: float(x[5]))
for row in table[:]:
    Ntable.add_row(row)
```

'