# Sort a file by first (or second, or else) column in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

This seems a very basic question, but I am new to python, and after spending a long time trying to find a solution on my own, I thought it's time to ask some more advanced people!

So, I have a file (sample):

```
ENSMUSG00000098737  95734911    95734973    3   miRNA
ENSMUSG00000077677  101186764   101186867   4   snRNA
ENSMUSG00000092727  68990574    68990678    11  miRNA
ENSMUSG00000088009  83405631    83405764    14  snoRNA
ENSMUSG00000028255  145003817   145032776   3   protein_coding
ENSMUSG00000028255  145003817   145032776   3   processed_transcript
ENSMUSG00000028255  145003817   145032776   3   processed_transcript
ENSMUSG00000098481  38086202    38086317    13  miRNA
ENSMUSG00000097075  126971720   126976098   7   lincRNA
ENSMUSG00000097075  126971720   126976098   7   lincRNA
```

and I need to write a new file with all the same information, but sorted by the first column.

What I use so far is :

```
lines = open(my_file, 'r').readlines()
output = open("intermediate_alphabetical_order.txt", 'w')

for line in sorted(lines, key=itemgetter(0)):
    output.write(line)

output.close()
```

It doesn't return me any error, but just writes the output file exactly as the input file.

I know it is certainly a very basic mistake, but it would be amazing if some of you could tell me what I'm doing wrong!

Thanks a lot!

### Edit

I am having trouble with the way I open the file, so the answers concerning already opened arrays don't really help.

Comment: Have you tried reading in by line and zipping?

Comment: Hi, I think this might be answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099669/python-sort-multidimensional-array-based-on-2nd-element-of-subarray, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183069/how-to-sort-multidimensional-array-by-column, ...

Comment: @bufh Not quite, those explain how to do what the OP is already trying.

Comment: @bufh Yes, I saw these answers, but the part with which I was stuggling with had to do with the way of reading my file, so an answer already talking about an array didn't help me.
Tank you anyway :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you're having is that you're not turning each line into a list. When you read in the file, you're just getting the whole line as a string. You're then sorting by the first character of each line, and this is always the same character in your input, `'E'`.

To just sort by the first column, you need to split the first block off and just read that section. So your key should be this:

```
for line in sorted(lines, key=lambda line: line.split()[0]):
```

`split` will turn your line into a list, and then the first column is taken from that list.

Answer (score 7):

If your input file is tab-separated, you can also use the csv module.

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
reader = csv.reader(open("t.txt"), delimiter="\t")

for line in sorted(reader, key=itemgetter(0)):
    print(line)
```

sorts by first column.

Change the number in

```
key=itemgetter(0)
```

for sorting by a different column.

Comment: You also need `from operator import itemgetter` at the beginning.

Comment: @domi: thank you for mentioning, i updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Same idea as SuperBiasedMan, but I prefer this approach: if you want another way of sorting (for example: if first column matches, sort by second, then third, etc) it is more easily implemented

```
with open(my_file) as f:
    lines = [line.split(' ') for line in f]
output = open("result.txt", 'w')

for line in sorted(lines):
    output.write(' '.join(line), key=itemgetter(0))

output.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write  a function that takes a filename, delimiter and column to sort by using `csv.reader` to parse the file:

```
from operator import itemgetter

import  csv

def sort_by(fle,col,delim):
    with open(fle) as f:
        r = csv.reader(f, delim=delim)
        for row in sorted(r, key=itemgetter(col)):
            yield row

for row in sort_by("your_file",2, "\t"):
     print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quickly with pandas as follows, with the data file set up *exactly* as you show it (i.e., with variable spaces as separators):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('csvdata.csv', sep=' ', skipinitialspace=True, header=None)
df.sort(columns=[0], inplace=True)
df.to_csv('sorted_csvdata.csv', header=None, index=None)
```

Just to check the result:

```
with open('sorted_csvdata.csv', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())

ENSMUSG00000028255,145003817,145032776,3,protein_coding
ENSMUSG00000028255,145003817,145032776,3,processed_transcript
ENSMUSG00000028255,145003817,145032776,3,processed_transcript
ENSMUSG00000077677,101186764,101186867,4,snRNA
ENSMUSG00000088009,83405631,83405764,14,snoRNA
ENSMUSG00000092727,68990574,68990678,11,miRNA
ENSMUSG00000097075,126971720,126976098,7,lincRNA
ENSMUSG00000097075,126971720,126976098,7,lincRNA
ENSMUSG00000098481,38086202,38086317,13,miRNA
ENSMUSG00000098737,95734911,95734973,3,miRNA
```

You can do multi column sorting by adding additional columns to the list in the colmuns=[...] keyword argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option. Similar to some of the ideas above. Basically, mysort is a function that will do the custom sorting for you which here is based on

```
def mysort(line):
    return line.split()[0]

with open("records.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.readlines()

for line in sorted(text, key=mysort):
    print line
```