# How can I sort IPv6 addresses based on a specific column in a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to sort a set of IPv6 addresses based on the nth column of the address.

Specifically they're stored in a file. If I have a file with these lines...

```
5128581|::|2001:4:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff||1

2747125|2001:6::|2001:5:0:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff||2

745044|2001:5:1::|2001:5:1:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff||3
```

I'd like to sort them by the 2nd column to get the following output:

```
5128581|::|2001:4:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff||1

745044|2001:5:1::|2001:5:1:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff||3

2747125|2001:6::|2001:5:0:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff||2
```

How can I do that?

I've found some useful questions about this ([Sort a file by first (or second, or else) column in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158103/sort-a-file-by-first-or-second-or-else-column-in-python), [Sorting IP Addresses in a Python Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088378/sorting-ip-addresses-in-a-python-script)) but I can't figure this out.

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]**. This means no images and no links.

Comment: I have provided example,,please review question again

Comment: But this isn't a [mcve].

Comment: @jpp means with 3 examples we cannot verify a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For parsing IPv6 address you could use `ipaddress` module. For sorting by n-th column you can use `key` parameter in `sorted()` function. This should give you an idea:

```
import ipaddress
from pprint import pprint

i = [('c1', 'b2', '2::'), 
     ('a1', 'c2', '1::'),
     ('b1', 'a2', '3::')]

out = sorted(i, key=lambda v: ipaddress.ip_address(v[2])) # sort by column 2 (0-indexed)
pprint(out, width=25)
```

Output:

```
[('a1', 'c2', '1::'),
 ('c1', 'b2', '2::'),
 ('b1', 'a2', '3::')]
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej but can you give example to sort from a file

Comment: @VikashKumar You need to read the contents of the file to variable first. Look around stackoverflow, there are plenty of examples how its done.

Comment: can we provide delimiter in sorted