# How do I find the mean of data that has been entered in a csv file from python?

Tags: python, csv

I want to find the average of three columns in a csv file created from Python.
My data is laid out like so:

```
[User Name, Score1, Score2, Score3]
```

for example

```
['James', 5, 8, 9]
```

I would like to find the average of the scores, `5`, `8`, `9`.

```
newrecord = "{user_name},{score_1},{score_2},{score_3}\n".format(user_name=userName, score_1=quiz_scores[0], score_2=quiz_scores[1], score_3=quiz_scores[2])
file=open('classroom1.csv', "a+")
file.write(newrecord)
file.close()
with open('classroom1.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)
```

I don't know what to do after this. Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific? Do you mean the average of the values in each row, or the average of each of the columns, or the average for all the columns combined?

Comment: You could do it easily with `pandas`. Do you have installed that package?

Comment: @timgeb: given the one example, I'd say it is the average for the 3 columns per name.

Comment: @AntonProtopopov: this is homework (the UK GCSE exam). Pandas is way overkill.

Comment: @timgeb The  average of all the numerical columns combined, so [James,5,8,9] 5+8+9=22 22/3=7.33333

Comment: @AntonProtopopov  I do not have Pandas

Comment: Kindly do not vandalize your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your `readCSV` object, when iterated over, will give you lists with strings, 4 values per row. Convert all but the first column to integers, then do your calculations on those integers:

```
for row in readCSV:
    name = row[0]
    scores = [int(c) for c in row[1:]]
    average = sum(scores) / len(scores)
    print('{}: {:.1f}'.format(name, average))
```

If you are using Python 2, then the `/` operator can cause problems as it'll use integer division when both the sum and the length are integers (which is the case here). Convert your numbers to `float` instead, or use `0.0` as the starting value for the sum (which makes sure the sum is a floating point number instead):

```
average = sum(scores, 0.0) / len(scores)
```

Comment: @BobStanley: You can use `format()` or `str.format()` to format your result, including specifying the number of decimal places.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, however how would I sort the data by average in ascending order.

Comment: @BobStanley: you do keep moving the goal posts! This post does answer your question. You can put the name and the average in a list, or add the average to the existing row. Build a new list with these rows and then sort those that list.

Comment: srt=sorted(row[0],total,reverse=True) #Like this ?

Comment: @BobStanley: See [How to sort multidimensional array by column?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20183069)

Answer (score 1):

I propose a `numpy` solution.

Consider the mockup file `testfile.txt` with the content

```
James, 5, 8, 9
Jeff, 10, 7, 3
Alice, 6, 7, 1
```

We can use `numpy.loadtxt`to load your file, then simply `map` the average to each row.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> map(np.mean, np.loadtxt('testfile.txt', usecols=[1,2,3], delimiter=','))
[7.333333333333333, 6.666666666666667, 4.666666666666667]
```

Comment: Like `pandas`, numpy is way overkill for this problem — especially for anyone new to Python.