# Sorting columns and lines of a matrix

Tags: python, sorting, matrix, line

I have this code wrote in Python that is for inputting a matrix:

```
matrix = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if not line: break
    values = line.split()
    row = [int(value) for value in values]
    matrix.append(row)
```

For example,a resulting matrix would be

```
[[9, 2, 4],
 [7, 8, 0]]
```

I would like to know if there's any way to sort the lines and columns of it? For example, sorting the first line would result in `[2, 4, 9]` and sorting the first column would result `[7, 9]`.

Comment: Unless you're looking for a nice programming exercise these operations are much easier using numpy.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sortColumn(matrix, column):
    tempCol = [row[column] for row in matrix]
    #The above generator equals to
    #tempCol = []
    #for row in matrix:
    #    tempCol.append(row[column])
    tempCol.sort()
    i = 0
    for row in matrix:
        row[colum] = tempCol[i]
        i += 1

def sortRow(matrix, row):
    matrix[row].sort()
```

Now if you want to sort columns of your matrix do

```
#Doesn't matter which row, all should have the same length
for column in range(0, len(matrix[0]): 
    sortColumn(matrix, column)
```

With rows it will be even simpler, I'd go for

```
for row in matrix:
    row.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if not line: break
    values = line.split()
    row = [int(value) for value in values]
    matrix.append(row.sort())
```

And then just print sort it by columns with:

```
sorted(matrix)
```