# Sorting an array of arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following data structure:

```
 [[[   512    520     1 130523]]

 [[   520    614    573   7448]]

 [[   614    616    615    210]]

 [[   616    622    619    269]]

 [[   622    624    623    162]]

 [[   625    770    706   8822]]

 [[   770    776    773    241]]]
```

I'm trying to return an object of the same shape, but only returning the rows with the 3 largest 4th columns (if that makes sense) (so in this case, that would be rows 1, 2 & 6)

What's the most elegant way to do this?

Comment: These are lists right? Just making sure because they aren't in proper syntax

Comment: are they numpy arrays?

Comment: Yes they are numpy arrays

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2828059/2922139

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sort the array, but as of NumPy 1.8, there is a faster way to find the N largest values (particularly when `data` is large):

Using [numpy.argpartition](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html):

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[[ 512,    520,     1, 130523]],
                 [[ 520,    614,    573,   7448]],
                 [[ 614,    616,    615,    210]],
                 [[ 616,    622,    619,    269]],
                 [[ 622,    624,    623,    162]],
                 [[ 625,    770,    706,   8822]],
                 [[ 770,    776,    773,    241]]])

idx = np.argpartition(-data[...,-1].flatten(), 3)
print(data[idx[:3]])
```

yields

```
[[[   520    614    573   7448]]

 [[   512    520      1 130523]]

 [[   625    770    706   8822]]]
```

`np.argpartition` performs a *partial* sort. It returns the indices of the array in partially sorted order, such that every `kth` item is in its final sorted position. In effect, every group of `k` items is sorted relative to the other groups, but each group itself is not sorted (thus saving some time).

Notice that the 3 highest rows are not returned in a same order as they appeared in `data`.

---

For comparison, here is how you could find the 3 highest rows by using `np.argsort` (which performs a full sort):

```
idx = np.argsort(data[..., -1].flatten())
print(data[idx[-3:]])
```

yields

```
[[[   520    614    573   7448]]

 [[   625    770    706   8822]]

 [[   512    520      1 130523]]]
```

---

Note: `np.argsort` is faster for small arrays:

```
In [63]: %timeit idx = np.argsort(data[..., -1].flatten())
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.6 µs per loop

In [64]: %timeit idx = np.argpartition(-data[...,-1].flatten(), 3)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.61 µs per loop
```

But `np.argpartition` is faster for large arrays:

```
In [92]: data2 = np.tile(data, (10**3,1,1))
In [93]: data2.shape
Out[93]: (7000, 1, 4)

In [94]: %timeit idx = np.argsort(data2[..., -1].flatten())
10000 loops, best of 3: 164 µs per loop

In [95]: %timeit idx = np.argpartition(-data2[...,-1].flatten(), 3)
10000 loops, best of 3: 49.5 µs per loop
```

Comment: This is great. I did find though that in some cases I wouldn't get things in the right order; is there anything in this method that doesn't guarantee perfect ordering?

Comment: This should work for any data whose dtype is a floating or int dtype. When using `np.argpartition(-data, 3)`, (note the minus sign) `NaNs` will be sorted at the end, so the highest values will be finite (if any exist). Note also that if `data`'s dtype is `object`, then the NaNs get sorted to the beginning, so then the highest values might contain NaNs. I'm not sure if this is answering your question. An example where things are not sorted in the right order would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) and specify that you want to sort by the 4th column:

```
l = [[[512,    520 ,    1, 130523]],
 [[   520 ,   614  ,  573,   7448]],
 [[   614 ,   616  ,  615,    210]],
 [[   616 ,   622  ,  619,    269]],
 [[   622 ,   624  ,  623,    162]],
 [[   625 ,   770  ,  706,   8822]],
 [[   770 ,   776  ,  773,    241]]]

top3 =  sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0][3], reverse=True)[:3]

print top3
```

will give you:

```
[[[512, 520, 1, 130523]], [[625, 770, 706, 8822]], [[520, 614, 573, 7448]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the structure of your list-of-lists in order to focus on the main issue. You can use `sorted()` with a customized `compare()` function:

```
my_list =  [[512, 520, 1, 130523], 
        [520, 614 , 573, 7448],
        [614, 616, 615, 210],
        [616, 622, 619, 269], 
        [622, 624, 623, 162], 
        [625, 770, 706, 8822], 
        [770, 776, 773, 241]]

def sort_by(a):
    return a[3]

sorted(my_list, key=sort_by)
print my_list[0:3] # prints [[512, 520, 1, 130523], [520, 614, 573, 7448], [614, 616, 615, 210]]
```