# Sorting a Numpy array in Python according to first column with second column following

Tags: python, numpy

How can I sort a n x 2 Numpy array in Python?

I know of the `np.sort` function but can only get it to sort 1 column independently of all the others.

I want the second columns' entries to follow that of the first.

Comment: Thanks @fhdrsdg I think you're right, but I cant figure out the syntax. If I have the array  a = np.array([[3,2],[4,5],[1,8],[9,4],[7,3]]) , how would I sort it according to the first column?

Comment: No sorry I was wrong. Use `a[a[:,0].argsort()]` (found in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column)). The 0 indicates the first column.

Comment: @Jonny you probably want `np.lexsort()`

Comment: Thank you @SaulloCastro, fhdrsdg's anwer also does the trick!

Comment: This is a form of lexical ordering, so @SaulloCastro's comment is the way to go, [doc here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html).

Comment: Ok good to know, thanks! Can you please indicate how lexsort should be implemented to achieve what I am looking for? The documentation doesn't indicate it very clearly for me.