# How to sort a numpy 2D array rows descending or ascending using a specific column indices

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

Lets say I have a numpy 2D array like this:

```
a = np.array([[3,6,7],[1,9,4],[ 3,7,8],[2,5,10]])
a
# array([[ 3,  6,  7],
#       [ 1,  9,  4],
#       [ 3,  7,  8],
#       [ 2,  5, 10]])
```

I need to sort the rows descending based on the first column and ascending on the second column to get the below result:

```
array([[ 3,  6,  7],
       [ 3,  7,  8],
       [ 2,  5,  10],
       [ 1,  9, 4]])
```

Doing this in Matlab was simple using sortrows(my_matrix,[-1 2]) where -1 for the first column descending and 2 for the second column ascending.

I wonder if there is a function like that in numpy.

Comment: Inspired by this question I added an example to the `duplicate` that applies `lexsort` to the 1st 2 columns.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column Is the suggested duplicate.  But seems there's interest in looking at what's different here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
print(a[npi.argsort((a[:,1], -a[:,0]))])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use pandas, you can pass a list into the `ascending` keyword to control the sort order of each field:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(a).sort_values([0,1], ascending=[False, True])

   0  1   2
0  3  6   7
2  2  5  10
1  1  9   4
```