# sorting matrix in numpy by column breaks array

Tags: python, sorting, matrix

I am interested in sorting a matrix of type

```
a = array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[0,0,1]])
```

by some column as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column). One straight forward answer given there is

```
a[a[:,1].argsort()]
```

However, this seems to break the array in some cases as also commented there. In my case I start with a `np.array` of `.shape` `(a,b)`. After the above code, I end up with an array of `.shape` `(a,1,b)`. What are potential reasons for this behaviour?

Comment: `a[a[:,1].argsort()].shape` from your example returns `(3,3)`. Numpy 1.11.0

Comment: @DimaLituiev Yes, I know. I can reproduce it too. But on another (large) matrix with different dimensions `a,b` I get shape `a,1,b`. I don't know what other information to give.

Comment: What is dimensionality of your matrix? What is dimensionality of  `a[:,1].argsort()` for your matrix?

Comment: @DimaLituiev Dimensionality of the matrix is `(10000, 784)`. Dimensionality of `a[:,1].argsort()` is `(10000, 1)`.

Comment: @DimaLituiev Following your comment: it seems `np.ravel(a[:,1].argsort())` solves the problem in my case.