# In place sorting by column fails on slices

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, in-place

I'm trying to sort a numpy array by a specific column (in-place) using the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2828371/1008938). For the most part it works, but it fails on any array that's a view on another array:

```
In [35]: columnnum = 2

In [36]: a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,7,5], [9,0,1]])

In [37]: a
Out[37]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 7, 5],
       [9, 0, 1]])

In [38]: b = a[:,(0, 2)]

In [39]: b
Out[39]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [9, 1]])

In [40]: a.view(','.join([a.dtype.str] * a.shape[1])).sort(order=['f%d' % columnnum], axis=0)

In [41]: a
Out[41]: 
array([[9, 0, 1],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 7, 5]])

In [42]: b.view(','.join([b.dtype.str] * b.shape[1])).sort(order=['f%d' % columnnum], axis=0)
ValueError: new type not compatible with array.
```

It looks like numpy doesn't support views of views, which makes a certain amount of sense, but I now can't figure out how to get the view I need for *any* array, whether it itself is a view or not. So far, I haven't been able to find any way to get the necessary information about the view I have to construct the new one I need.

For now, I'm using the `l = l[l[:,columnnum].argsort()]` in-place sorting method, which works fine, but since I'm operating on large datasets, I'd like to avoid the extra memory overhead of the `argsort()` call (the list of indexes). Is there either a way to get the necessary information about the view or to do the sort by column?

Comment: My hunch is you're going to be out of luck.  I don't know that much about the numpy internals, but it looks to me like you are trying to push the view beyond what can be done without copying the data.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Probably. I just wanted to see if anyone here had any clever hacks. My current solution is just to error on data that can't be viewed and tell the caller to make a copy first... Ugly, but at least I can provide a useful error message.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1019]: a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,7,5],[9,0,1]])
In [1020]: b=a[:,(0,2)]
```

This is the `a` that you are sorting; a structured array with 3 fields.  It uses the same data buffer, but interpreting groups of 3 ints as fields rather than columns.

```
In [1021]: a.view('i,i,i')
Out[1021]: 
array([[(1, 2, 3)],
       [(4, 7, 5)],
       [(9, 0, 1)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

By the same logic, you try to `view` `b`:

```
In [1022]: b.view('i,i')
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: Changing the shape of non-C contiguous array by
descriptor assignment is deprecated. To maintain
the Fortran contiguity of a multidimensional Fortran
array, use 'a.T.view(...).T' instead
  #!/usr/bin/python3
....
ValueError: new type not compatible with array.
```

But if I use 3 fields instead of 2, it works (but with the same warning):

```
In [1023]: b.view('i,i,i')
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning:...
Out[1023]: 
array([[(1, 4, 9), (3, 5, 1)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

The problem is that `b` is `Fortran order`. Check `b.flags` or

```
In [1026]: a.strides
Out[1026]: (12, 4)
In [1027]: b.strides
Out[1027]: (4, 12)
```

`b` is a copy, not a view.  I don't know, off hand, why this construction of `b` changed the order.

Heeding the warning, I can do:

```
In [1047]: b.T.view('i,i,i').T
Out[1047]: 
array([[(1, 4, 9), (3, 5, 1)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

A default copy (order c) of `b` can be viewed as 2 fields:

```
In [1042]: b1=b.copy()
In [1043]: b1.strides
Out[1043]: (8, 4)
In [1044]: b1.view('i,i')
Out[1044]: 
array([[(1, 3)],
       [(4, 5)],
       [(9, 1)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

A footnote on: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

> The memory layout of an advanced indexing result is optimized for each indexing operation and no particular memory order can be assumed.

====================

`b` in this case was constructed with advanced indexing, and thus is a copy, even a true view might not be viewable in this way either:

```
In [1052]: a[:,:2].view('i,i')
....
ValueError: new type not compatible with array.

In [1054]: a[:,:2].copy().view('i,i')
Out[1054]: 
array([[(1, 2)],
       [(4, 7)],
       [(9, 0)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

The view is selecting a subset of the values: 'i,i,x,i,i,x,i,i,x...', and that does not translated into structured dtype.

The structured view of `a` does: '(i,i,i),(i,i,i),...'

You can select a subset of the fields of a structured array:

```
In [1059]: a1=a.view('i,i,i')
In [1060]: a1
Out[1060]: 
array([[(1, 2, 3)],
       [(4, 7, 5)],
       [(9, 0, 1)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
In [1061]: b1=a1[['f0','f2']]
In [1062]: b1
Out[1062]: 
array([[(1, 3)],
       [(4, 5)],
       [(9, 1)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

But there are limits as to what you can do with such a view. Values can be changed in `a1`, and seen in `a` and `b1`.  But I get an error if I try to change values in `b1`.
 This is on the development edge.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Am I right to then assume that a check of `a.flags.c_contiguous` being `True` is enough to guarantee that the array will be viewable in this way?

Comment: It might be; I haven't used that kind of test.

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming there's no other way to sort in place by column either, is there?

Comment: How about `np.lexsort`?

Comment: Maybe, but that still has the problem of creating an array of indexes. That's workable, but I'd rather avoid it.