# Numpy Argsort with Radix Sort

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, machine-learning, decision-tree

In Decision Trees, we can improve the speed of finding a good split by first sorting the training samples by a certain feature column. However, since all the features are numbers, it's suggested that Radix sort might actually be the fastest. I can't figure out how to use Radix sort to sort a Numpy array by a column though.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column), we can sort a numpy array by column (for example, column 1) using mergesort, quicksort, or heapsort:

```
a[a[:,1].argsort()]
```

[Here's](http://www.geekviewpoint.com/python/sorting/radixsort) an implementation of radix sort in Python that works well.

How do you combine the two? I'd love to get something of the following behavior:

```
a[a[:, 1].argsort(kind="radix")]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No.  At least not without digging deep into both that `radixsort` code, and the `argsort` code.  Have you tested that `radix` sort on your data, ie on `a[:,1]`?