# array within an array sort python numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Python newbie.. this might be fairly straight-forward.. I tried looking through the other questions but no luck..

I have a nd array that looks like this:

```
pos=[[[567 341 741 450]]

[[803 513 839 538]]

[[733 446 881 539]]

[[656 411 800 512]]

[[513 308 534 324]]

[[579 356 602 373]]

[[549 335 576 355]]

[[558 335 608 366]]]
```

I want to do a sort based on the first column inside the array..Basically [[513 308 534 324]] should be the first element.. How do I go about it ?

Comment: `sorted(pos, key=operator.itemgetter(0))`

Comment: @OzgurVatansever This question is about a numpy array, not a Python list.

Comment: @Gerry doesn't matter. Solutions both I proposed and the ones in the duplicate work for `np.array` types as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column