# Sorting the nodes of a tree in breadth-first order in numpy

Tags: arrays, list, sorting, numpy, dictionary

Suppose I have the following `numpy` array:

```
arr = numpy.array([[1, 7], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [5, 6]])
```

Suppose I choose a specific key, in this case `2`. Then I would like the sorting to be the following:

```
arr_sorted = [[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 3], [1, 7], [3, 4], [3, 5], [5, 6]]
```

The idea is first start with all the elements with key as 2, and then go to the entries whose keys were the values of the previous key.

Starting with 2, the entries are `[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 3]`. The next keys after 2 will therefore be 0, 1, 3. There are no entries with 0 as key. There is one entry with 1 as the key: `[1, 7]`. There are two entries with 3 as the key: `[3, 4], [3, 5]`. The next unprocessed key is `7`, but it has no entries. Same goes for 4. There is a single entry with 5 as the key: `[5, 6]`. 6 has no entries.

Is there any `numpy` or `dictionary` tricks to achieve this?

My nearest attempt is the following:

```
def bfs_finder(d, start):
  queue = deque([start])
  seen = [start]
  results = []
  while queue:
    _vertices = queue.popleft()
    current = [i for i, a in enumerate(d) if len([x for x in a if x in _vertices])==1 and i not in seen]
    curr1 = [a[1] for i, a in enumerate(d) if len([x for x in a if x in _vertices]) == 1 and i not in seen]
    if len(current)>0:
        results.extend(curr1)
        queue.extend(curr1)
        seen.extend(current)
  return results
```

But, I am actually getting an error of `current = [i for i, a in enumerate(d) if len([x for x in a if x in _vertices])==1 and i not in seen]
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable`. Any suggestions on how to fix this error, as well as if there are any good improvements would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite understand how you get `arr_sorted`.

Comment: Please do some additional explanation and/or give more examples of input and desired output. Also, please show the not so efficient way of doing the sorting, the one you have already found and implemented yourself.

Comment: @Tai I have added more explanations.

Comment: How does 7 come up in there?

Comment: @MadPhysicist 7 has the key 1, and one was the value of the previous key 2.

Comment: @konstant. Thanks. So we basically step along, using the last unprocessed value to keep adding batches of keys. Gotcha

Comment: @konstant. While this is an interesting problem, I have to ask if you have actually made any effort to solve it yourself, besides asking for a solution on SO.

Comment: Ping me once you edit in your own attempt and an explanation of why it's not satisfactory.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I do have an attempt. Unfortunately, there is an error in the code which I haven't been able to fix. But, I have posted my attempt regardless.

Comment: @jpp. What was the point of the deleted answer?

Comment: Make `seen` a `set` for one thing...

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I misread the question, hence deleted!

Comment: `x for x in a`: `a` is an integer. Did you mean `range(a)` or something?

Comment: What happens to remaining elements when you run out of processed values?

Comment: I've changed the title of the question to better describe what you're actually asking - your data is a tree, of the form `[[parent_1, child_1], [parent_2, child_2], ...]`

Comment: What determines the order of `[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 3]` in your example? Are they left in the order they started in? Are they sorted by child id?

Comment: The order in which they started.

Comment: Say you start with `[2, 1], [2, 0], [2, 3]`, what would be the result after sorting?

Comment: `[[2, 1], [2, 0], [2, 3], [1, 7], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6]]`.

Comment: @konstant Are you willing to accept an answer which returns `[[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 3]]` for @Tai's example?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) to hold the processed keys and a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) or similar stack-compatible container to hold the processed values (a list would work too). Since you have numpy arrays, you could pre-sort the array by rows and extract swaths from it using [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) on the first column.

The algorithm would be something like this:

1. Sort the array by rows
2. Pre-allocate the output array
3. Add the key to the `stack`
4. While stack is not empty

   5. Pop a key off the stack
   6. If key is in the set, discard and continue
   7. Add key to the set
   8. Find key in first column (start and end indices) using bisection
   9. If key is present, copy swath to output array

The sort operation is `O(n log(n))`. The bisection algorithm will be as well (approximately `n` searches with `O(log(n))` each). Your total algorithmic complexity should therefore not exceed `O(n log(n))`, which is pretty good for a weird sorting algorithm.

Sorting by rows seems to be fastest using [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35624868/2988730), and fortunately `np.searchsorted` accepts a `sorter` argument.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import deque

def bfs_finder(d, start):
    sorter = np.argsort(d[:, 0])
    done = set()
    todo = deque([start])
    output = np.empty_like(d)
    pos = 0
    while todo:
        key = todo.popleft()
        if key in done:
            continue
        done.add(key)
        left = np.searchsorted(d[:, 0], key, 'left', sorter)
        if left >= d.shape[0] or d[sorter[left], 0] != key:
            continue
        right = np.searchsorted(d[:, 0], key, 'right', sorter)
        next = pos + right - left
        output[pos:next, :] = d[sorter[left:right], :]
        todo.extend(output[pos:next, 1])
        pos = next
    return output

arr = np.array([[1, 7], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [5, 6]])
print(bfs_finder(arr, 2))
```

[IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/bktDB7)

```
[[2 0]
 [2 1]
 [2 3]
 [1 7]
 [3 4]
 [3 5]
 [5 6]]
```

This solution assumes that you won't have any keys in the original that are missing from the output. If you run into that problem, subtract the set of the first column from the set of processed keys, and decide how you want to handle the remainder.

You might be able to gain some additional mileage by passing the entire stack to each call of `searchsorted` instead of doing it one element at a time.

Comment: @jpp. Here you go.