# Python: Sorting an array with respect to a column

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, columnsorting

I have the following matrix

```
 a=np.array([[1,-2],[2,-3]])
```

and i want to obtain this one

```
[[2,-3],[1,-2]]
```

meaning i have sorted the matrix with respect to the 2nd column.

I have tried the following code that don't work

```
  a=np.array([[1,-2],[2,-3]])
  a.sort(axis=1)
  print(a)
```

which give me

```
 [[-2,1],[-3,2]]
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting arrays in NumPy by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column)

Comment: duplicate question, check [sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column)
a simple solusion is a[a[:,1].argsort()]