# Rearrange the result number ascendingly

Tags: python, ip

Any way for rearranging the sorting of the failed logged in times according the number from smaller to larger? For example the first 5 rows is 3, 6th is 5 and last rows is 6.

### Ip address with number failed logged in more than 2 times

```
ip_address
128.15.0.2                  **3**

126.11.0.8                  **3**

0:0:0:0:0:ffff:c001:101     **3**

192.168.1.5                 **5**

192.168.1.15                **6**

0:0:0:0:0:ffff:a093:1800    **3**

0:0:0:0:0:ffff:212:d        **3**
```

Comment: Can you post the input data structure and expected output.

Comment: `print('\nIp address with number failed logged in more than 2 times ')`      
`print('------------------------------------------------------------')`         
`print(df2['num_failed_logins'])`                                                                                             Here is my code and I just want to know any way to sorting the output number from smaller to bigger.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort'` Prompt out this error

Comment: `df2.sort_values(['num_failed_logins'])` ?

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways. I found a fast way in this post [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2828121/10690964).

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([["128.15.0.2",3],
["126.11.0.8",3],
["0:0:0:0:0:ffff:c001:101",3],
["192.168.1.5",5],
["192.168.1.15",6],
["0:0:0:0:0:ffff:a093:1800",3],
["0:0:0:0:0:ffff:212:d",3]])


x[x[:,1].argsort()]
```

Comment: This way is just sorting it before run the output. I want to know how to arrange the number when the output are shown.

Comment: Then the answer of @Rakesh should do the job