# Is there an alternative of std::memcmp in cuda?

Tags: cuda, gpu

Is there an alternative of std::memcmp in cuda?
I want to compare the whole rows in a matrix, on cpu, simply call std::memcmp is ok, is there a high efficient way to do this on gpu?

The operation is like this:
[Sorting arrays in NumPy by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column)

Comment: Do you need the signed result, or is a boolean result acceptable for your use case?

Comment: boolean is ok, equan or not equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not functionally identical to `std::memcmp`, the thrust template library includes a comparison reduction operation [`thrust::equal`](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__comparisons.html) which will return true or false when the elements of two iterator ranges compare identically.

If you actually require the sign of the comparison, you would need to write your own implementation.