# Sorting a 2by2 Numpy array by one column in descending order

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I am trying to somewhat elegantly sort a 2 by 2 Numpy array so that the letters keep being grouped up with their respected start float values. But the float values should be sorted from highest to lowest.

```
this = {"z": 1.6, "aaaaaaaaaaaaa": 0, "w": 6, "v": 4}
orThis = [['z' '1.6']
 ['aaaaaaaaaaaaa' '0']
 ['w' '6']
 ['v' '4']]

shouldBecomeThis = [['w', 6. ],
                 ['v', 4. ],
                 ['z', 1.6],
                 ['aaaaaaaaaaaaa', 0 ]]
```

the reason why the result is supposed to look exactly like  this, is because i want to feed it into a pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

def plotTable(data, header):        
  fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  fig.patch.set_visible(False)
  ax.axis('off')
  ax.axis('tight')     
  df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["gene", header])
  #top line throws error if i feed it data= [('w', 6. ) ('v', 4. ) ('z', 1.6) ('aaaaaaaaaaaaa', 0. )]       
  ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center')            
  fig.tight_layout()                       
  plt.show()

foo = [['w', 6. ],
      ['v', 4. ],
      ['z', 1.6],
      ['aaaaaaaaaaaaa', 0 ]]

plotTable(foo, "SomeTableHeader")
#Plots a table.
```

```
sortData = {"z": 1.6, "aaaaaaaaaaaaa": 0, "w": 6, "v": 4}
npArray = np.array(list(sortData.items()))
sortData = np.array(list(sortData.items()), dt)
sortData.view('<U16,<f8').sort(order=['f1'], axis=0)
sortData = np.flip(sortData, 0)
print(sortData)
#best i got so far: [('w', 6. ) ('v', 4. ) ('z', 1.6) ('aaaaaaaaaaaaa', 0. )]
```

I already looked this one up, but it couldn't make it work: [Sorting arrays in NumPy by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column)

Comment: Which of these variables is your input and which the desired output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
this = {"z": 1.6, "aaaaaaaaaaaaa": 0, "w": 6, "v": 4}
array=np.array([[key,val] for (key,val) in this.items()])
sortedArr = array[array[:,1].argsort()[::-1]]
print(sortedArr)
```

Comment: thanks, this one i actually very neat as it's so easy to read

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple `sorted` should help you get that output -

```
d = {"z": 1.6, "aaaaaaaaaaaaa": 0, "w": 6, "v": 4}
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
```

```
[('w', 6), ('v', 4), ('z', 1.6), ('aaaaaaaaaaaaa', 0)]
```

You can apply a `dict()` on the output to get back a dictionary if you need.

Comment: thanks a lot! been sitting on this for way to long :)