# Sorting 2d array by rows in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I would like to rearrange the rows in a python numpy array according to descending order of the first column.
For Example,

```
([[2,3,1,8],
  [4,7,5,20],
  [0,-2,2,0]])
```

to be converted to

```
([[0,-2,2,0],
  [2,3,1,8],
  [4,7,5,20]])
```

such that first column converts to `[0,2,4]` from `[2,4,0]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting arrays in NumPy by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column)

Answer (score 3):

Regular `sorted` does it:

```
print(sorted([[2,3,1,8], [4,7,5,20], [0,-2,2,0]]))
```

But if you only want to sort by the first columns, use:

```
print(sorted([[2,3,1,8], [4,7,5,20], [0,-2,2,0]], key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

They both output:

```
[[0, -2, 2, 0], [2, 3, 1, 8], [4, 7, 5, 20]]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you intend to get `numpy` operation:

```
arr = arr[arr[:,0].argsort()]
```