# Sort numpy 2d array by multiple columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D numpy array that looks like this

```
array([[5, 0],
       [3, 1],
       [7, 0],
       [2, 1]])
```

I'd like to (sub) sort by each column (say right to left) to get this:

```
array([[5, 0],
       [7, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 1]])
```

How can I do that in numpy?

Comment: Did you try to change the column index like `array[np.argsort(array[:, 0])]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting arrays in NumPy by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column)

Comment: Yes, that doesnt keep the sorted second column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy includes a native function for sub-sorting by columns, `lexsort`:

```
idx = np.lexsort((arr[:,0], arr[:,1]))
arr_sorted = arr[idx]
```

Alternatively, you can use pandas syntax if you're more familiar; this will have some memory/time overhead but should be small for < 1m rows:

```
arr = [
    [5,  0],
    [3,  1],
    [7,  0],
    [2,  1]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=arr).sort_values([1,0])
arr_sorted = df.to_numpy()
```

output (both):

```
array([[5, 0],
       [7, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 1]])
```

Comment: Ah yes, but it is a very large array unfortunately

Comment: @FlorisFancypants how large is very large?  This should be acceptable up to a few million rows anyway

Comment: oh, its like 10000, but the lexsort works too, thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.lexsort` to sort an array on multiple columns:

```
idx = np.lexsort((a[:,0], a[:,1]))

a[idx]
```

Output:

```
array([[5, 0], 
       [7, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 1]])
```