# Sort array by first column

Tags: python

I have an array called `foundFaces`.  However, I want to order the faces from left to right, so that its easy to guess which face is which.

When I print the array  I get this:

```
[[414.7081      92.99516    482.82443    177.7601       0.9049758 ]
 [278.0241      96.27542    344.90128    186.57086      0.88056326]
 [542.65515     69.08964    609.4397     162.48027      0.88008916]]
```

The left most column is the x1 value, which I would like to sort by.  So the final array I want is this:

```
[[278.0241      96.27542    344.90128    186.57086      0.88056326]
 [414.7081      92.99516    482.82443    177.7601       0.9049758 ]
 [542.65515     69.08964    609.4397     162.48027      0.88008916]]
```

How can I achieve this in python? Do I have to loop through and create my own array or is there a fancy way to do it? I'm still new to python so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you are using numpy: `foundFaces = foundFaces[foundFaces[:, 0].argsort()]`, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column

Comment: foundFaces = sorted(foundFaces, key=lambda x:x[0]) - or without numpy.

Comment: @ewz93 Brilliant, I knew there'd be some numpy/pythonesc way of doing it.  Thanks.  Can you put it as answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted(foundFaces, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using NumPy:

```
foundFaces = foundFaces[foundFaces[:, 0].argsort()]
```

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column).