# How to sort a numpy array that contains floats and strings in numeric order?

Tags: python, numpy

I've got a numpy array that contains some numbers and strings in separate columns:

```
a = np.array( [[ 3e-05, 'A' ],
[ 2, 'B' ],
[ 1e-05, 'C' ]]
)

print(a[a[:, 0].argsort()])
```

However, when try to sort it based on the first column using `.argsort()` it's sorted in string order not numeric order.

```
[['1e-05' 'C']
 ['2' 'B']
 ['3e-05' 'A']]
```

How do I go about getting the array to sort in numeric order based on the first column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting arrays in NumPy by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column)

Comment: While your list of lists contains numbers and strings, the array you made from it is just strings   That should be clear from the sorted output.  To get a numeric sort, you need numbers, not just strings that look like numbers.  Have you considered using the Python sort with key

Comment: @CarlosHorn Not quite -- that solution works if none of the numbers in the array are in e-notation.

Comment: I edited your title because the key here is that the numpy array was created using floats and strings, and was converted to an array of strings. BTW "e-notation" is nothing special. It just denotes a regular `float` `a*(10**b)` as `aEb`. The numbers themselves are still the same floating-point numbers.

Comment: If you are not forced to use numpy, I would recommend to use pandas which IMHO is a better choice for representing data of various types. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values to solve your sorting problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `a` is an array of *strings*, as evidenced by `a.dtype` being `'<U32'`. Therefore, `a[:, 0].argsort()` will sort the column in *lexical order*.

To sort a column as numbers, it needs to be converted to numbers first, by calling `.astype` before `.argsort`:

```
a = np.array( [[ 3e-05, 'A' ],
[ 2, 'B' ],
[ 1e-05, 'C' ]]
)

print(a[a[:, 0].astype(float).argsort()])
```

Output:

```
[['1e-05' 'C']
 ['3e-05' 'A']
 ['2' 'B']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the creation of the array, you could create a [structured array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html) instead of a regular array.

```
dtypes = [('value', np.float64), ('label', '<U32')]

a = np.array( [( 3e-05, 'A' ),
               ( 2, 'B' ),
               ( 1e-05, 'C' )], dtype=dtypes)
```

Now, `a` is a structured array with separate dtypes for the first and second columns -- the first column is an array of floats, and the second column is an array of strings.

*Note that the array is defined as a list of **tuples**.* This is important: defining it as a list of lists and then specifying `dtype=dtypes` won't work.

Now, you can sort by a column like so:

```
a_sorted = np.sort(a, order=['value'])
```

which gives:

```
array([(1.e-05, 'C'), (3.e-05, 'A'), (2.e+00, 'B')],
      dtype=[('value', '<f8'), ('label', '<U32')])
```

You can get a row or column of this structured array like so:

```
>>> a_sorted[0]
(1.e-05, 'C')

>>> a_sorted['value']
array([1.e-05, 3.e-05, 2.e+00])
```