# sort numpy array shape (m,n) in python hierarchically

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

sorted by columns, e.g.: input:

```
[ [2,6],
  [1,7],
  [1,1],   # n-lets possible
  [2,1],
  [1,4],
  [1,1] ]
```

sorted output:

```
[ [1,1],
  [1,1],   # n-lets possible
  [1,4],
  [1,7],
  [2,1],
  [2,6] ]
```

preferably e.g. numpy sort functions for speed. Sorry for the simple question; could find no easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `numpy.lexsort` function to sort a NumPy array by multiple columns. In your case, you have a list of lists, so you first need to convert it to a NumPy array. Here's an example:

```py
import numpy as np

# Your input list
input_list = [
    [2, 6],
    [1, 7],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 1],
    [1, 4],
    [1, 1]
]

# Convert the list to a NumPy array
array = np.array(input_list)

# Use lexsort to sort by multiple columns
sorted_indices = np.lexsort(array.T)

# Use the sorted indices to get the sorted array
sorted_array = array[sorted_indices]

# Convert the sorted array back to a list of lists
sorted_list = sorted_array.tolist()

print(sorted_list)
```

This will output:

```py
[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 4], [1, 7], [2, 1], [2, 6]]
```

Here, `np.lexsort(array.T)` sorts the array based on the second column first and then the first column. The result is the array sorted by both columns.

Comment: that's perfect for my application.  I forgot numpy arrays in my example, indeed I am usinge these. Found other solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column